# Gnome Shell extension window list doesn't utilize space in top panel

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

As you can see in the image , gnome shell extension window list doesn't utilize left space properly. There is some limit approximately in the middle of the screen.
After that it doesn't expand. Is there any way to customize the window list extension to use proper space according to our needs ... like I can apply a particular amount of boundary between status icon(notification icon) and windows list.

Answer (score 1):

my problem is solved after using this extension... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/51/extend-left-box/